# markup for go language in appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Is there a markup library (such as markdown or reST) in go language? preferebly

- working with [html/template](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/)
- available for appengine

I have checked [here](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/library-bindings) and searched google but nothing seems to be showing up. (could be just bindings as well)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/knieriem/markdown - A translation of peg-markdown (an implementation of Markdown in C, using a PEG grammar) into Go

https://github.com/russross/blackfriday - Blackfriday: a markdown processor for Go

Both are pure Go and should work fine on App Engine, you should be able to expand templates either after of before rendering the markdown to HTML.